# How to not extract CSS into separate files in vue-cli3?

Tags: webpack, vue-cli

In the vue-cli3 project, while we building the project, it seems that it would separate the project into  `js` file and `css` file automatically by `mini-css-extract-plugin`. But now I just want only `js` file. So I think I need to turnoff `mini-css-extract-plugin` in `vue.config.js`.

I want to know how to do it, thanks for ur help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solve this problem by this.

```js
> vue.config.js

process.env.VUE_CLI_CSS_SHADOW_MODE = true; // close the config about sperating css from js

module.exports = {
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.optimization.delete('splitChunks') // close splitChunks
        config.output
            .filename('app.js')
            .library('@[library]/[sub-project]')
            .libraryTarget('amd') 
            .end()
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but for others stumbling over this like I did:

The existing answer kinda works but is misleading. `VUE_CLI_CSS_SHADOW_MODE` is used when building web components and might have other side effects, now and in future versions.

The official way to toggle css extraction is to use the `css.extract` property as described in [the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#css-extract) which configures `mini-css-extract-plugin` under the covers.
By default, css extraction is off for development builds (as to enable hot reloading) and on for production builds.

To turn off CSS extraction production builds add `vue.config.js` (or extend an existing one) in the project root containing

```
module.exports = {
  css: {
    extract: true
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

As I view `vue-cli-service` code, I find out how to do it. There is a code like this.

```js
const shadowMode = !!process.env.VUE_CLI_CSS_SHADOW_MODE
...
const shouldExtract = extract !== false && !shadowMode
...
if (shouldExtract) {
  rule
    .use('extract-css-loader')
    .loader(require('mini-css-extract-plugin').loader)
    .options({
      hmr: !isProd,
      publicPath: cssPublicPath
    })
```

So I just need to set `VUE_CLI_CSS_SHADOW_MODE` true.

So add `process.env.VUE_CLI_CSS_SHADOW_MODE = true;` in `vue.config.js` and it works!